# GDAL GeoPackage (GPKG) vs Shapefile (SHP) performance

Tags: geospatial, gdal, shapefile, geopackage

I'm trying to decide which format of vector spatial data should be used on a embedded device.
The main operation imposed on these vectors will be to rasterize the with GDAL C++ API so they can be converted to pixmaps on the screen.
I have read that GPKG should be faster than SHP on read and write operations. But in my experience the SHP is MUCH faster and MUCH less memory consuming in generating rasters than GPKG.

For example rastering a exact same part from GPKG and SHP files with gdal_rasterize:

**SHP**

```
time gdal_rasterize -burn 20 -burn 20 -burn 255 -burn 255 -l N44_VesiAlue -ts 512 512 -ot byte -te x1 y1 x2 y2 ./N44/N44_VesiAlue.shp vesi-shp.tif
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

real    0m0,433s
user    0m0,366s
sys 0m0,021s
```

**GPKG**

```
time gdal_rasterize -burn 20 -burn 20 -burn 255 -burn 255 -l vesialue -ts 512 512 -ot byte -te x1 y1 x2 y2 mtkshp100k.gpkg vesi-gpkg.tif
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

real    0m4,439s
user    0m4,244s
sys 0m0,150s
```

The GKPK takes a significantly more time and also very much RAM (more than the whole memory available on the target).

Is rastering actually a operation where SHP performs better. Why do my test conflict with the overall idea that GPKG is better performing than SHP.

Comment: Where do you get the idea that, with GDAL, writing a GPKG file is faster than writing a shapefile? That is certainly contrary to my experience. People argue in favor of GPKG for some good reasons, but I do not believe that the speed of writing a new file is one of them. Another question would be why you write the data to disk in the first place.

Comment: @RobertHijmans Thank you for your answer. It might be that I just was first met with the hype of using GPKG. Even though it has it's pros maybe the shape file is the format to go with in my case because speed and memory usage is critical. And why I would write them to the disk or ramfs (/tmp) is to store/cache them temporarily so they are fast and easily accessible from the target program.

Comment: ESRI Shapefile is an archaic format, I wouldn't start using it today. For speed something like geoparquet is probably a good choice, but it always depends on the application of course. Rasterization in and of itself is quite expensive, so it's hard to imagine I/O being a significant bottleneck.
https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/parquet.html